# How do I use a custom weapon with custom stats in a private game?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In TF2, if I wanted to get a custom weapon with special qualities (such as Valve quality), how would I do it? (See [Karma Charger's videos on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/user/KarmaBookSimon) concerning weapon demonstrations)

Comment: I've edited your post. The revisions include clarification on who KarmaCharger is and what your intended message was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to give yourself weapons of irregular/unobtainable (through trade) qualities, you would need to use server plugins. If you're not familiar with plugins, they are essentially add-ons to a server (notable examples of popular plugins being !RTD and !ROBOT).

You can give yourself weapons of these qualities using the SourceMod [[TF2Items] Give Weapon](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=141962) plugin. Keep in mind this is a **server plugin**, meaning that simply dragging the files into your TF2 folder would be wasting your time - research on how to create your own dedicated server ([Windows](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Windows_dedicated_server) or [Linux](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Linux_dedicated_server)) if you're interested in recreating some of what Karma Charger does.